# Color theme is not set up properly in .emacs file

Tags: linux, emacs, elisp, color-scheme

I have color-theme package installed in emacs and I want to set a theme at the start up of emacs so I added this to my .emacs file:

```
(color-theme-initialize)
(color-theme-clarity)
```

But when I restart emacs, the theme is not selected. I don't get any errors but the theme I select is not being applied unless I manually do `M-x color-theme-clarity`. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: This is not a programming question.  You should try SuperUser.

Comment: @Duck If you are going to be telling people to take their Emacs questions elsewhere, you might want to consider sending them over to [Emacs.SE](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: @itsjeyd - I wasn't aware of it until now but I will in the future.  In any case the linux tag is often overrun with questions that don't involve programming.  Perhaps there is a better way to lead people to check the stackexchange site that is most appropriate for their question?

Comment: @Duck Maybe. You should ask that question again on [meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) :)

Comment: @Duck, According to the [Help Center](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic), questions about "software tools commonly used by programmers" are on topic on Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I'm not sure whether this is the case for your theme problem, I've had similar theme-related issues because of other initialisation-time things overruling the theme loading.

Perhaps using `after-init-hook` would allow the theme load to happen after whatever other thing in your initialisation is causing the problem?

You could try something like the following, perhaps (note: untested):

```
(add-hook 'after-init-hook
          (lambda ()
            (load-theme 'color-theme-clarity)))
```

(You might need to use `(color-theme-clarity)` rather than the `(load-theme...)` expression depending on whether that theme is based on the theme package or not.)

At worst case you might be able to use `(run-with-timer ...)` or `(run-with-idle-timer ...)` (again, untested), to arrange for theme load to happen a few seconds after the end of initialisation to simulate your manual workaround. It would be kludgey, though.

Comment: Yes using `after-init-hook` seems to have solved my problem. Thanks!

Comment: Very glad to hear it. Thanks for letting us know.

Answer (score 0):

You need to load library `color-theme.el`.  Put this code before what you have already:

```
(require 'color-theme)
```

(And you might not even need the call to `color-theme-initialize`.)

And of course `color-theme.el` needs to be in your `load-path`.

(`color-theme-initialize` initializes the themes themselves, so they can be loaded.  It does not load library `color-theme.el`.)

Comment: I added `(require 'color theme)` but still nothing changed. And I had installed color-theme from elpa so I think it is loaded automatically.

Comment: You can check whether it is loaded by looking at the value of variable `features`. You can check whether it is in your `load-path` by looking at variable `load-path`.

Comment: `color-theme.el` is in my `.emacs.d` folder so I think it is in my `load-path`. I did `(add-to-list 'load-path "~/.emacs.d")` to be safe but the result is the same. How can I check the `features` variable?

Comment: `C-h v features`.  You can also check variable `load-history` the same way, but it is enough to check `features`. It is also enough to check any command defined in `color-theme.el` that is not autoloaded by trying it with `M-x`.